# org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution cannot be created when tapping jobs

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-xd, kryo

I am attempting to use aggregated events to allow successful completion of a job to kick off another.  Problem is, is that I get a "Class cannot be created (missing no-arg constructor)" exception for JobExecution.

Here are the attempted taps:

```
stream create --name trigger_myjob--definition "tap:job:prerequisitejob.job > filter --expression=payload.getExitStatus.equals(T(org.springframework.batch.core.ExitStatus).COMPLETED) > queue:job:myjob" --deploy
stream create --name debug_trigger --definition "tap:job:prerequisitejob.job > log --name=TX.DEBUG --expression=payload.getExitStatus"
stream create --name debug_harder_trigger --definition "tap:job:prerequisitejob.job > log"
```

In each case, I get a stack trace indicating that the rabbit listener failed to create the message, ultimately caused by:

```
Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Class cannot be created (missing no-arg const
ructor): org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.newInstantiator(Kryo.java:1050)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.newInstance(Kryo.java:1062)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.create(FieldSerializer.java:228)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:217)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:626)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.integration.bus.serializer.kryo.PojoCodec.doDeserialize(Po
joCodec.java:41)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.integration.bus.serializer.kryo.AbstractKryoMultiTypeCodec$1.execute(AbstractKryoMultiTypeCodec.java:63)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.pool.KryoPoolQueueImpl.run(KryoPoolQueueImpl.java:43)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.integration.bus.serializer.kryo.AbstractKryoMultiTypeCodec.deserialize(AbstractKryoMultiTypeCodec.java:60)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.integration.bus.serializer.kryo.PojoCodec.deserialize(PojoCodec.java:30)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.integration.bus.serializer.CompositeCodec.deserialize(CompositeCodec.java:72)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.integration.bus.serializer.CompositeCodec.deserialize(CompositeCodec.java:78)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.integration.bus.MessageBusSupport.deserializePayload(MessageBusSupport.java:588)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.integration.bus.MessageBusSupport.deserializePayload(MessageBusSupport.java:573)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.integration.bus.MessageBusSupport.deserializePayloadIfNecessary(MessageBusSupport.java:556)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.integration.rabbit.RabbitMessageBus.access$600(RabbitMessageBus.java:101)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.integration.rabbit.RabbitMessageBus$ReceivingHandler.handleRequestMessage(RabbitMessageBus.java:748)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
        ... 37 more
```

What is causing this exception, and how do I fix it?  Is there any other way to go about having jobs trigger one another in spring-xd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out after asking this that our architect had manually replaced jars, Kryo among them.  The behavior observed will not happen in a vanilla Spring XD installation.